# Can't connect to Synology with Telnet or SSH

Tags: telnet

Despite enabling the service on my DS107e I have been unable to connect to it with Telnet or SSH. Telnet gives me the following:

`Connecting To 192.168.0.4...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed`

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**Solution:**

The Synology has an internal Firewall function. So, as well as turning on the Telnet (and/or SSH) the access through the firewall needs to be enabled. This is done by accessing the firewall settings on the control panel. Hopefully this will help someone!

Comment: can you ping 192.168.0.4? does SSH give you the same 'could not connect to port' message?

Comment: It wouldn't ping and I got the same message with SSH. However, see my solution above; something that I didn't find in any of the tutorials I found.